# How to get user and cart data in authentication guard on refresh?

Tags: angular, authentication, checkout, spartacus-storefront, angular-router-guards

I am having problem with `CheckoutAuthGuard` on spartacus storefront. When browser refresh button is pressed on any page in checkout process, guard redirects me to a login due to missing user and cart info.

I have used `CustomCheckoutAuthGuard` like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {
  ActiveCartService,
  AuthRedirectService,
  AuthService,
  RoutingService,
  User,
  UserToken,
} from '@spartacus/core';
import { combineLatest, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {CheckoutConfigService} from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Injectable()
export class CustomCheckoutAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    protected routingService: RoutingService,
    protected authService: AuthService,
    protected authRedirectService: AuthRedirectService,
    protected checkoutConfigService: CheckoutConfigService,
    protected activeCartService: ActiveCartService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest([
      this.authService.getUserToken(),
      this.activeCartService.getAssignedUser(),
    ]).pipe(
      map(([token, user]: [UserToken, User]) => {
        if (!token.access_token) {
          if (this.activeCartService.isGuestCart()) {
            return Boolean(user);
          }
          if (this.checkoutConfigService.isGuestCheckout()) {
            this.router.navigate(['checkout-login']);
          } else {
            this.routingService.go({ cxRoute: 'login' });
          }
          this.authRedirectService.reportAuthGuard();
        }
        return !!token.access_token;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

It is very similar to default `CheckoutAuthGuard` from spartacus. I also switched this guard for all relevant checkout components:

```
    CheckoutOrchestrator: {
      component: CheckoutOrchestratorComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard, CheckoutGuard],
    },
    CheckoutProgressMobileTop: {
      component: CheckoutProgressMobileTopComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard],
    },
    CheckoutProgressMobileBottomComponent: {
      component: CheckoutProgressMobileBottomComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard]
    },
    CheckoutProgress: {
      component: CheckoutProgressComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard]
    },
    CheckoutDeliveryMode: {
      component: DeliveryModeComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard, ShippingAddressSetGuard]
    },
    CheckoutPlaceOrder: {
      component: PlaceOrderComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard]
    },
    CheckoutReviewOrder: {
      component: ReviewSubmitComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard]
    },
    CheckoutShippingAddress: {
      component: ShippingAddressComponent,
      guards: [CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, CartNotEmptyGuard, CheckoutDetailsLoadedGuard]
    }
```

But on refresh, user from `ActiveCartService` is `undefined` and also `this.activeCartService.isGuestCart()` returns `undefined`.

This is all for guest checkout and unfortunately I can not tell what is behavior for logged in user. It is because we use CDC, and currently with CDC there is a bug where any refresh redirects to home page, so this guard is completely bypassed. More on this issue [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/9597).

Can someone give me advice what is best to try out here? Maybe some cart state needs to be synced with local storage, or `combineLatest` is wrong `rxjs` function here? Or something else? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, it is fixed in Spartacus version 3.0 you can see the issue we opened [here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/9037). At the moment there is no plan to back port this change to a version prior to 3.0.

The issue was caused by the fact that the guard checks were run before the cart was loaded loaded.

If you need this solution before 3.0, I recommend that you override the out of the box `CheckoutAuthGuard` with a custom version of it. You should add the `this.activeCartService.isStable()` value to the `combineLatest` stream and `filter` on "cart stable". [Here](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/pull/9436/files#diff-4249ae379812857b5903df26157d9ea5403ddeb3ddf1ee1230725acc38c6cc41R39-R41) you can see what I mean.

Here is how you should provide your custom guard so it replaces the default guard:

(in app.module.ts or other module imported in AppModule)

```
providers: [
     ...,
     {
      provide: CheckoutAuthGuard,
      useClass: CustomCheckoutAuthGuard, //or whatever your guard class is named
    }
]
```